# Fullcalendar resourceTimeGrid month view render

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, render, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Hi guys i want to separate a month into 4-5 weeks so that each week will have 7 days.I cannot find a way to display the whole month in this view only the current week as you can see each week column contains the actual week days, but i would like to render the whole month with this scheme.

```
  this.calendarOptions = {
  headerToolbar: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'prev next'
  },
  defaultAllDay:false,
  aspectRatio: 2.45,
  editable: false,
  slotMinWidth: 75,
  selectable: false,
  eventClassNames: ['mt-1'],
  eventResourceEditable: false,
  eventOverlap: false,
  initialView: 'resourceTimeGridSevenDay',
  resourceLabelClassNames: ['p-0'],
  resourceGroupLabelContent: (arg) => {
    return {html: `<strong>${arg.groupValue}</strong> `};
  },
  resourceLabelContent : (arg) => {
    return {html: `<span> ${arg.resource._resource.title}</span> `};
  },
  slotLabelContent: (arg) => {
    return {html: ` `};
  },

  eventClick: (arg) => {
    console.log('event click')
  },
  now: new Date().toISOString(), 
  resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Sponsor/Protocol',
  resourceAreaWidth: '10%',
  views: {
    resourceTimeGridSevenDay: {
      type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
      duration: {days: 7},
      slotDuration: { weeks: 4 },
    }
  },
  events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources=2',
  fixedWeekCount: false,
  rerenderDelay: 2,
  progressiveEventRendering: true,
  
  showNonCurrentDates: false,
  initialDate: new Date().toISOString(),
 
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can create exactly what you've shown in your screenshot using fullCalendar, but it's possible to get fairly close, and it might be good enough.

In the documentation for the `slotLabelFormat` setting, it mentions that for the timeline view it can be configured with multiple rows in the label area.

So you could still use the "month" view to get the correct number of days, but set up the slot labelling like this:

```
views: {
  resourceTimelineMonth: {
    slotLabelFormat: [
      { week: 'long', }, // top level of text
      { weekday: 'short', day: '2-digit' } // lower level of text
    ],
  }
},
```

It shows the week number as the week of the year rather than week of the month, and the date format is similar but not identical (and will vary a bit depending on your locale anyway).

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BawNMEp

If you want even more control of the exact date format, you'd need to use one of the plugins as mentioned in the Date Formatting documentation.

Documentation:

- [slotLabelFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat)
- [Date Formatting](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting)